# Magento 2, Magento Unprotected XML

Tags: magento2, xml, security

I have a Magneto 2.2.3 instance and when we check for security scan it is showing below error:

> We have determined that your Magento installation's configuration
>   file(s) are publicly accessible over HTTP

**user.ini**

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you solved it?

Comment: Please check my answer @Piyush

Answer (score 2):

I added the below code into my .htaccess file.
You can check with .htaccess file in the **root path** or in the **Pub folder**.

```
# Deny access to files with extensions .ini, .psd, .log, .sh
<FilesMatch "\.(ini|psd|log|sh)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

It helps me. Hope this will help others. :)

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your magento install isn't using this file. So get file access and in your web root and just rename the file. If your site still works you are good.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your nginx config.

`location ~ \.user\.ini$ {
    deny all;
}`